Omnipay Alipay (Global) send() method is undefined
In Omnipay Alipay (Global), send() method is not working as expected.
$response = $gateway->completePurchase($params)->**send()**;

I received error message like this,
Call to a member function send() on array {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function send() on array

I'm currently doing hosted checkout using Alipay (Global), but I received error message like this,
Call to a member function send() on array {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to a member function send() on array


Check if your gateway is configured correctly, try puchase options
